# K2 : Redirect user after login to User Blog Page

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2, login, redirect

I am using K2 extension in a website. When a user logs in, I want the page to be redirected to the user page automatically where he can see his posts. I am using K2 login module. When the user logs in, the module shows an option `my page`. This is the page I want the page to be redirected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way (out of the box) that K2 can dynamically create the link to the user page is to use the K2 User module. However, the "Login Redirection" setting uses Menu Items, only. Unfortunately, there is no K2 menu item that can be dynamically updated for the logged in user--you must set the menu item for a specific user, instead.

The K2 user module can be docked (fixed position) on the top so the redirection is not needed and the user can access his page from the entire site. And, with a little template customization, you could get the module to only display the link to the user's page. Doing this instead of redirecting the user every time he/she logs in may be a better solution.

---

Reference: http://www.joomlaworks.net/forum/k2-en/37367-menu-item-link-to-k2-users-blog#132747

Comment: Thanks Michael! I did this and fixed the module in one position in profile page. and when user logs in, I redirected him to profile menu item.

Comment: Sounds great, glad to help!